# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает кнопка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не работает кнопка при запуске через Spyder 3.2.8, который находится в дистрибутиве Anaconda. А когда скачал интерпретатор с https://www.python.org/ и запустил, кнопка заработала. Может быть, в Spyder какие-то настройки надо исправить?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

                            # Оси координат #
def draw_axis(ax):
    ax_max = 7
    ax_min = 0
    ax.set_xlim(ax_min, ax_max)
    ax.set_ylim(ax_min, ax_max)
    ax.set_zlim(ax_min, ax_max)
    ax_dx = 1
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(ax_dx))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(ax_dx))
    ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(ax_dx))
    ax_col = 'k'
    ax.quiver(ax_min, 0, 0, ax_max, 0, 0, color=ax_col, lw=1.5,
              arrow_length_ratio=0.1)
    ax.quiver(0, ax_min, 0, 0, ax_max, 0, color=ax_col, lw=1.5,
              arrow_length_ratio=0.1)
    ax.quiver(0, 0, ax_min, 0, 0, ax_max, color=ax_col, lw=1.5,
              arrow_length_ratio=0.1)
    ax.text(ax_max, 0, 0.15, 'x', size=16, color=ax_col)
    ax.text(0, ax_max, 0.15, 'y', size=16, color=ax_col)
    ax.text(0, 0, ax_max, 'z', size=16, color=ax_col)
    ax.text(0, 0, 0.15, '0', size=16, color=ax_col)


                            # Нарисовать точки #
def draw_points(ax, points):
    for p in points:
        ax.scatter3D(p[1], p[2], p[3], c='r')
        ax.text(p[1], p[2], p[3]+0.15, p[0], size=18, color='r')

                        # Нарисовать проекции точек #
def draw_projections(ax, points):
    for point in points:
        # на плоскость x0y
        ax.plot([point[1], point[1]], [point[2], point[2]], [point[3], 0],
                ls='--', c='m')
        ax.plot([point[1], point[1]], [point[2], 0], [0, 0],
                ls='--', c='m')
        ax.plot([point[1], 0], [point[2], point[2]], [0, 0],
                ls='--', c='m')
        ax.text(point[1], 0, 0.15, point[1], size=16, color='m')
        ax.text(0, point[2], 0.15, point[2], size=16, color='m')

        # на плоскость x0z
        ax.plot([point[1], point[1]], [point[2], 0], [point[3], point[3]],
                ls='--', c='m')
        ax.plot([point[1], point[1]], [0, 0], [point[3], 0],
                ls='--', c='m')
        ax.plot([point[1], 0], [0, 0], [point[3], point[3]],
                ls='--', c='m')
        ax.text(0, 0, point[3]+0.15, point[3], size=16, color='m')

        # на плоскость y0z
        ax.plot([point[1], 0], [point[2], point[2]], [point[3], point[3]],
                ls='--', c='m')
        ax.plot([0, 0], [point[2], point[2]], [point[3], 0],
                ls='--', c='m')
        ax.plot([0, 0], [point[2], 0], [point[3], point[3]],
                ls='--', c='m')
    plt.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def click_1(event):
        draw_projections(ax, points)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.view_init(azim=36, elev=20)
    points = [['A', 3, 4, 5]]

    #ax.set_axis_off()
    ax.grid()
    draw_axis(ax)
    draw_points(ax, points)
    axes_button_1 = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1])
    button_1 = Button(axes_button_1, '#1')
    button_1.on_clicked(click_1)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: А почему вы решили, что она не работает?

Comment: у меня ваш код (как есть) отрабатывает правильно - при нажатии на кнопку отрисовывается параллелепипед

Comment: Не работает кнопка при запуске через Spyder 3.2.8. А когда скачал интерпретатор с https://www.python.org/ и запустил, кнопка заработала. Но мне хотелось бы через Spyder запускать.